# Is there any way to modify the name of parameter that transfers "ref" from "Like" button?

Tags: facebook, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins

The way to track referrals is described in the "Like" button documentation:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

If you provided "ref" parameter then facebook will add two parameters in the URL to your site:

1. fb_ref
2. fb_source

Is there any way to configure what are URL parameter names that facebook will use to pass these data?

The reason I would like to change that is to have same "ref" parameter name for all social networks (I didn't investigate, but some other social networks could have different parameter name and I don't really like idea to support whole variety of them).

Any feedback is very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to change this - you'll have to either log each network separately, or just hard-code those values in for Facebook and use `ref=` elsewhere

Comment: Is there any reference to confirm that?

Comment: Well, the like button docs explain how to track via reference, and this uses ref in the input and fb_ref and fb_source on the output; there isn't documentation itemising the things you *can't* do